Find Integral using Trapezoid method
Find using the trapezoid method.
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos{x}}{x} \,dx$$
By choosing $n=4, $ the step is
$h=\frac{b-a}{n}=0.25$
Attempt:
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos{x}}{x} \,dx =$$
$$\frac{0,25(f(45)+f(0,25))}{2} +$$
$$\frac{0,25(f(0,25)+f(0,5))}{2} +$$
$$\frac{0,25(f(0,5)+f(0,75))}{2} +$$
$$\frac{0,25(f(0,75)+f(90))}{2} +$$
$$0,125(\frac{\cos{45}}{45} + 2(\frac{\cos{0,25}}{0,25})+ 2(\frac{\cos{0,5}}{0,5}) + 2(\frac{\cos{0,75}}{0,75}) + \frac{\cos{90}}{90}) \approx ...$$
My answer was wrong. Correct answer in the back of the book is: $0,291$.

Are you really dividing by $45$, $90$, etc.? What do you think is wrong with that?

@JohnDouma to be honest, I don't know.

The step $h$ is wrong.

With $a=\frac{\pi}{4}, b=\frac{\pi}{2}, n=4$: $h=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{\pi}{16}\ne 0.25$

I'll write you a solution, give me a minute.

@gpmath as I suspected.

@SigmaAlgebra Thanks a lot ;-).

You're welcome! Hope that helps!

Consider $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{x}\ dx$$
Taking $n=4$, then $$h=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}}{4}=\frac{\pi}{16}$$
So, applying the trapezoid formula:
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{x}\ dx\approx \frac{\pi}{16}\left(\frac{f(\pi/4)+f(\pi/2)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^3 f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{16}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{16}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}+\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{\cos\left(\frac{(4+k)\pi}{16}\right)}{\frac{(4+k)\pi}{16}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{16}+\pi\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{\cos\left(\frac{(4+k)\pi}{16}\right)}{(4+k)\pi}=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{16}+\pi\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{16}\right)}{5\pi}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}{6\pi}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{16}\right)}{7\pi}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{16}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{16}\right)}{5}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}{6}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{16}\right)}{7}\approx$$
$$\approx 0,088+0,111+0,064+0,028=0,291$$

Can you expand the h part, I want to know how you get that answer?  Pi/16.

Yes, sure! $$h=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{\pi}{16}$$

Thanks a lot

It's a pleasure for me. If you have any other doubts, just ask!

Question: Why do you use the Sigma notation and sum?

Because it's a sum?  Granted, it's a sum of only three items, so it's easy to convert to $+$ notation.

@SaraJönsson it is just a compact writing of the sum which I then expanded. It's a very common notation for sums ;)
